# iTunes creates its own playlists when I add folders

Tags: playlist

When I Add a number of folders to iTunes it automatically makes playlists of them which I find annoying. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

It should only do that if you drag the folder to the playlists list on the left - drag to anywhere else & it doesn't.
Intentional behaviour.